# Class 'List<_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot>' has no instance getter 'docs'

Tags: flutter

I'm getting this error when I click on the button in firebase data is getting store but its not displaying the data. Please let me know where I, doing wrong or what changes I need to make to the code so solve the error.... I'm learning the Flutter myself and I don't know what to do next.

```dart
    Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "Trip",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 15,
                            color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    FutureBuilder(
                        future: getPosts(),
                        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
                          var indexLength = snapshot.data.length;
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            return Container(
                                height: 200,
                                child: snapshot.data.docs.map((document) {
                                  int _index;
                                  PageView.builder(
                                      itemCount: indexLength,
                                      onPageChanged: (int index) =>
                                          setState(() => _index = index),
                                      itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                                        return ListTile(
                                            title: Text(snapshot.data.docs[i]
                                                .data()['tripname'])
                                            //napshot.data[index]["tripname"]),
                                            );
                                      });
                                }));
                          } else {
                            return Center(child: Text("Loading"));
                          }
                        }),
                  ],
                )
```

[[image: Screenshot1]

Answer (score 0):

Before you do `var indexLength = snapshot.data.length;` try:

```
if (snapshot.hasError) {
   return Text("Something went wrong");
}

if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
   return Text("Document does not exist");
}

if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
   // put your code here...
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply... Still gives same error